# Hide expand/collapse symbol or deactivate spec. rows in jqGrid subgrid

Tags: jqgrid, subgrid

I have a grid with a subgrid: Only the **first** row of the Main grid need to have a subgrid.

The solutions I found by Google and [http://www.trirand.com/....i:subgrid&s[]=hidecol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid&s%5b%5d=hidecol) 
doesn't work.

Is there a quick and dirty (hard coded) solution?

Answer (score 14):

Hiding the 'subgrid' column with `jQuery("#grid_id").hideCol('subgrid');` remove full column which can be used to expand or collapse the subgrid, so you can not use the way in your case.

I suggest you to clear contain of the 'subgrid' column and unbind the 'click' event for the cells inside of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handle:

```
loadComplete: function() {
    $("td.sgcollapsed:not(:first)","#list").unbind('click').html('');
}
```

you will have the following results:
[image]
(You can see the corresponding example live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectiveSubGrid.htm)). It's important to understand, that the [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event will be called on any page, so on the second page you will have subrgid also only on the first row.

If you need to implement more complex logic in choosing of the rows which need have subgrids you can use following code

```
loadComplete: function() {
    var grid = $("#list");
    var subGridCells = $("td.sgcollapsed",grid[0]);
    $.each(subGridCells,function(i,value){
        if (i!==0) {
            $(value).unbind('click').html('');
        }
    });
}
```

The code above do the same as the statement `$("td.sgcollapsed:not(:first)","#list").unbind('click').html('')`, but you can easy modify the last version of the code to implement more complex behavior.

**UPDATED**: If you need detractive subgrid only for some row identified by the `rowid` you can use

```
$("#"+rowid+" td.sgcollapsed",grid[0]).unbind('click').html('');
```

(see live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectiveSubGridRowId.htm)) inside of the `loadComplete`. If you need deactivate subgrid for all rows which id is not equal to `rowid` you can make something like following

```
$('td.sgcollapsed:not("#'+rowid+' td.sgcollapsed")',grid[0]).unbind('click').html('');
```

(see live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectiveSubGridNotRowId.htm))

**UPDATED**: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) now have new feature described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32744570/315935): `hasSubgrid` callback which can be specified in `subGridOptions`. It allows to inform jqGrid which rows should don't have subgrids.

Comment: Can you please solve my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662475/something-similar-to-treegrid-in-jqgrid) in your free time. Thanks

Comment: Awesome... I didn't need exactly need this. But, the way its explained. It helped me. Thank You Again +1