# jqGrid - how to trigger action after it loaded complely?

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee, jqgrid, pagination

I use jqGrid in my webpage. Can anyone help me to perform any action when each time the navigator buttons clicked in the navigator of the gird? also when entering the page number in the page number textbox. I tried using onPaging: function(), but I am not sure how to use it as I am new to this jqGrid. Thank you in advance.

I need to perform the action once the grid is loaded with data completely after clicking on any of the navigator buttons. for example,

```
    alert("Hi there!!");
```

I need to perform. glad to get idea from Someone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to execute some action **after** "the grid is loaded with data completely" then you should use `loadComplete` callback instead of `onPaging`. If the page will be changed the grid will be reloaded and `loadComplete` callback will be called at the end.

Comment: thank you for the answer Oleg..but as I mentioned I am new to this jqGrid; it will be helpful if you can let me know some code wise example for the  'loadComplete' action which will be performed exactly after everytime the next/previous button is clicked and the  grid is loaded with data completely. Thank you again, Oleg.!

Comment: @yuva443: You are welcome! Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectiveSubGridNotRowId.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4538656/315935) for example. In general **there are no difference between loading the grid and the loading of the next grid of the page**. `loadComplete` callback will be called just after every loading. Initial loading is also loading of one page (the page number 1).

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg; I am almost done with your help now. Actually before you posted this answer I referred another answer of yours which was about onMouseover action in the grid. My work has to be completed all with the clicks inside the grid; hence I utilized that one!! ;) I'll try this one also..thankz again..from now I will ask you only whatever doubts am getting in programming..!! :P have a great day, Oleg..

Comment: @yuva443: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand from your last comment what is your current problem. Could you reformulate your question (your current problem) more clear?

Comment: I mean all set for now, Oleg; no problems; thank you !! and I mean that YOU ARE GREAT!!

Comment: @Oleg What if the loadonce is true?

Comment: @DeepakMishra: Could you describe more details what you mean? What scenario you try to implement? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? It's unclear for me what you want to do `onPaging` or *after* the page is loaded or updated.