# How to show jqGrid subgrid on certain rows only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, subgrid

I created a grid with multiple sub-grid levels using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) and with a little help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10178440/837623). Here is what I have currently:

[image: Grid current status]

I am trying to modify it in a way to only show the sub grid if there is data to show. In other words if the `count > 0`. Logically I tried to add a condition (pseudo code below, based on previously mentioned answer):

**Original Code**

```
var gridParams = {
    datatype: 'local',
    data: myGridData,
    colNames: ['Column 1', 'Column 2'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'col1', width: 200 },
        { name: 'col2', width: 200 }
    ],
    ...
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
        var subgridTableId = subgridDivId + "_t";
        $("#" + subgridDivId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "'></table>");
        $("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: mySubgrids[rowId],
            colNames: ['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'c1', width: 100 },
                { name: 'c2', width: 100 },
                { name: 'c3', width: 100 }
            ],
            ...
        });
    }
}

$("#grid").jqGrid(gridParams);
```

**Adjusted Code**

```
var gridParams = {
    datatype: 'local',
    data: myGridData,
    colNames: ['Column 1', 'Column 2'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'col1', width: 200 },
        { name: 'col2', width: 200 }
    ],
    ...
}

// Condition added HERE
if (count > 0)
{
    gridParams.subGrid = true;
    gridParams.subGridRowExpanded = function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
        var subgridTableId = subgridDivId + "_t";
        $("#" + subgridDivId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "'></table>");
        $("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: mySubgrids[rowId],
            colNames: ['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'c1', width: 100 },
                { name: 'c2', width: 100 },
                { name: 'c3', width: 100 }
            ],
            ...
        });
    }
}

$("#grid").jqGrid(gridParams);
```

but that just fails miserably:

[image]

Is this simply not supported or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question then you want to remove "+" (expand subgrid) icon for rows which have no elements in the subgrid. In the case you can follow the old trick described in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4538656/315935). You can add `loadComplete` handle which removes some "+" icons from the grid having `subGrid: true` option. You need just know rowids of all rows of the grid which have no subgrid and do for the rows

```js
$("#" + rowid + ">td.sgcollapsed").unbind("click").html("");
```

**UPDATED**: I posted the modification of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which allows easy implement the requirement without the above hack.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/hasSubrgid.htm) demonstrates the new feature. The implementation is very easy. It contains `hasSubgrid` callback inside of `subGridOptions`. The callback have `options` which is object with the properties `rowid`, `data` and two less important properties `iRow` and `iCol`. The code of the demo uses `options.data` which represent the data of the row. The demo creates subgrid only if input row have `tax` higher as 20.

```js
subGridOptions: {
    hasSubgrid: function (options) {
        return parseFloat(options.data.tax) > 20;
    }
}
```

You can use `mySubgrids[options.data.rowid].length` in your case, if I correctly understand the format of your input data.

Comment: I was thinking of not populating an empty grid in the fist place but this hgack totally does the trick! Thank you!

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: What I mean is also not population the subgrid. Instead of that you can include in **parent grid** the hack. It will prevent adding of "+" icon in the row of the parent grid, so no subgrid will be ever populated for the row. By the way I prepared modification of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (the fork of jqGrid which I develop starting with the end of 2014) which introduces `hasSubgrid` callback in `subGridOptions`. The callback informs jqGrid in which rows should be added the "+" icon and in which not. I'll publish the modification soon and inform you.

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: I posted the modification [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/6922b6e184490426ffdbc23cd9ed74faebbee166). So you can download the latest code from GitHub or to use [the urls](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit).

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: I posted **UPDATED** part of my answer with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/hasSubrgid.htm) which demonstrates the new feature of free jqGrid.

Comment: Perfect Thank you! I will have a look at it as well :)

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: You are welcome!

Comment: @Oleg
4 years later and your hack for unbinding the click has just saved me an immense amount of hair pulling. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @plum0: I'm grad that old posts still help. Thanks for writing the comment!

Comment: @Oleg Where can i find documentation on where the `">td.sgcollapsed"` part comes from? I am currently trying to do a conditional to determine if a pager is needed and am looking for information on how to do that.

Comment: @plum0: I can't follow you. First of all which **version** of jqGrid you use and fron which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? What you mean with "documentation" of internal structures like `">td.sgcollapsed"`? jqGrid has source source code and one can see that js code create subbgrid using classes like `ui-sgcollapsed`, `sgcollapsed` and `sgexpanded` and CSS use the classes too.