# jqGrid subGrid how to hide "+" expand icon if we don't have data sub grid

Tags: jqgrid

When i don't have any data in subgrid i am getting empty grid in subgrid. Also need to hide the expand icon. Below is the code i used.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    var myData = [
            {
                id: "10",
                c1: "My Value 1",
                c2: "My Value 1.1",
                subgridData: [
                    { id: "10", c1: "aa", c2: "ab" },
                    { id: "20", c1: "ba", c2: "bb" },
                    { id: "30", c1: "ca", c2: "cb" }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "20",
                c1: "My Value 2",
                c2: "My Value 2.1",
                subgridData: [
                    { id: "10", c1: "da", c2: "db" },
                    { id: "20", c1: "ea", c2: "eb" },
                    { id: "30", c1: "fa", c2: "fb" }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "30",
                c1: "My Value 3",
                c2: "My Value 3.1"
            }
        ],
        $grid = $("#list"),
        mainGridPrefix = "s_";

    $grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: myData,
        colNames: ["Column 1", "Column 2"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "c1", width: 180 },
            { name: "c2", width: 180 }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
        pager: "#pager",
        gridview: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        sortname: "c1",
        viewrecords: true,
        autoencode: true,
        height: "100%",
        idPrefix: mainGridPrefix,
        subGrid: true,
        subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
            var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
                pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, rowId);

            $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
            $subgrid.jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", pureRowId).subgridData,
                colModel: [
                    { name: "c1", width: 178 },
                    { name: "c2", width: 178 }
                ],
                height: "100%",
                rowNum: 10000,
                autoencode: true,
                autowidth: true,
                gridview: true,
                idPrefix: rowId + "_"
            });
            $subgrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
                .children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv")
                .hide();
        }
    });
    $grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false});
});
```

My output like below screenshot. How to remove the expand icon and subgrid if we don't have any data for subgrid.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this behavior. My output like below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the problem depends on the version and the fork of jqGrid, which you use. I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) fork and have implemented `hasSubgrid` callback, which I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32744570/315935) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/hasSubrgid.htm)).

The items of your input data contains `subgridData` property as the array of subgrid data. Thus one should create the subgrid only if `subgridData` property is defined and `subgridData.length > 0`. Thus you need just to upgrade to the current version of jqGrid (4.13.4 or 4.13.5pre) and to add the option

```js
subGridOptions: {
    hasSubgrid: function (options) {
        // the options contains the following properties
        //     rowid - the rowid
        //     iRow - the 0-based index of the row
        //     iCol - the 0-based index of the column
        //     data - the item of the data, with the data of the row
        var subgridData = options.data.subgridData;
        return subgridData != null && subgridData.length > 0;
    }
}
```

to the main grid. The callback `subGridOptions.hasSubgrid` will be called *during building the grid data*, thus it works very effective like `rowattr`, `cellattr` and custom formatters.

Comment: How to hide the sub grid header in free jqGrid. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: @Karthikeyan: You are welcome! Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14265456/315935). The code of `resizeStop` will be even very easy, because free jqGrid contains `setGridWidth` out of the box.

Comment: @Oleg, the SubgridOptions is not working in my grid. I just tested with returning false & true but it's not considering the hasSubgrid return value, It's showing the plus icon even the return value is "False". Please advise on this.

Comment: I just tried like --->   subGridOptions: {
    hasSubgrid: function (options) {
               return false;
    }
}

Comment: @MdAslam: Which **version** of free jqGrid you use? Do you use free jqGrid or an old jqGrid, which don't have support of `hasSubgrid` of `subGridOptions`?

Comment: @Oleg, jqGrid 4.15.6-pre

Comment: @Oleg, sorry,  have updated my version, Its working fine but  I am not able to get the rowdata or rowId from the Options parameter. Is there a way to identify the row_Id or cellvalue in the hasSubgrid function?

Comment: @MdAslam: You should provide the demo, which demonstrates the problem. I tried with https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/utLj3ndm/ and everything works. You can modify it and post me back.

Comment: @MdAslam: You need just examine the `options` parameter of `hasSubgrid`. You can include `debugger` inside of `hasSubgrid` and see that `options` is object like `{ rowid: "50", iRow: 1, iCol: 1, data: {itemdata} }`, for example, `{ rowid: "50", iRow: 1, iCol: 1, data: { name: "test5", invdate: "2007-10-31", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", note: "note5", id: "50" } }`

Comment: @Oleg, Thank you so much it's working fine.  And one small problem that when I expand my grid column's cell width manually some design issue is coming.  I have used the below options in the grid, is there any problem because of those?  Because If I use old version of JQgrid that design issue is not coming but If I update the l4.15.6 pre then the design prob coming when I expand a column length in the grid    (shrinkToFit: false,  forceFit: false,
          autowidth: false,
          rownumbers: true,...)

Comment: @MdAslam: Sorry, but I'm not understand exactly what you mean. The problem sounds complex and can't be solved without debugging of the demo, which reproduces the problem.