# Hide and disable the expand icon

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid with a grid as subgrid that has a grid as subgrid.
Let´s call them grid, subgrid#1 and subgrid#2.

I want to hide and disable the expand icon for the rows of the subgrid#2 depending the value of a column.

The problem is that some rows of the subgrid#1 have the same id of the rows of the subgrid. So, in some cases, instead of hiding and disabling the click of the rows of the subgrid#2, the row of the subgrid#1 is affected.

This is the code that i'm using to hide and disable the click:

```
$(this).find("td.ui-sgcollapsed>a").hide();
$(this).find("td.ui-sgcollapsed").unbind('click').html('');
```

Comment: 1. Have UNQUE IDs 2. It is PREFERABLE to not have numeric IDs 3. Use .off instead of unbind, but no need to off the click if you hide it: `$(this).find("td.ui-sgcollapsed>a").toggle(columnvalue!=something);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write always, which version you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Free jqGrid has since a long time the feature, which you can use. One can define `hasSubgrid` callback inside of `subGridOptions`, which inform jqGrid whether to create subgrid icon in the row. The callback `hasSubgrid` get the data of row as parameter. So it's very easy to implement your requirement. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40021497/315935) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32744570/315935) with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/hasSubrgid.htm) for more details.